# Product Listing back-end for React Native Multi-Vendor Marketplace

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've just started building this multi-vendor marketplace idea I've had for a while. I am using react native, xcode, cocoapods, firebase&firestore, and javascript as my language. My app is a 3-sided marketplace (B2B2C) and contains 5 different user groups, 4 of which will have the ability to list products and only 2 will have the ability to purchase products. My question is would firestore be a good approach to handling these listings and if so how would you set up the product listing feature backend for each of the 4 user groups considering each product listing contains slightly different input/data fields. Also if anyone has leads/guides on product/post listings, adding/fetching user inputed data and queries, and/or react native multi-vendor marketplace apps please let me know, I just need some guidance to get started.

Comment: I used to work on the marketplace with multi-vendors with Firestore and worked well. Searching products or merchants is not handled by Firestore but you can integrate with services like Algolia.

Most people worry about pricing but it's not something to spend more time on in the early stage. when the app scale exponentially, you can migrate to another document database like Dyanamo DB or MongoDB.

You can reach me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com for further.

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel Thank you very much for your comment. I started looking into postgreSQL but I will definitely reach out for further guidance, much appreciated.